# How to create two different random color groups in NetLogo 6.1.1?

Tags: random, colors, netlogo

How to create two different random color groups in NetLogo 6.1.1?

I am trying to create two different groups from the group of 250 turtles. The starting situation is that all 250 turtles are gray and then they will turn to yellow and pink groups one by one.

This code of mine makes all turtles in the beginning to be gray and then they will all turn to pink. I do not want this but I want two randomly made groups where pink turtles is typically either larger or smaller group of turtles  than the yellow group of turtles in the end of the code run.

I just started to code with NetLogo 6.1.1. Thank you for understanding and all help and have a nice day.

````
[
  time

  person
]


turtles-own [ x ]

to setup

  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  set time  0
  create-turtles 250 

  [
      setxy random-xcor random-ycor 

  ]  

  ask turtles

  [
    set shape "person"
    set size 1
    set color gray
  ]

  end


to go 

  ask turtles


 [

    show random 2 = x

    if x = 1 [set color yellow] 
    if x = 0 [set color pink]
  ]


end ```
````

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any place where the values for the turtle variable `x` are set, so they will always have the default value of `0`.  In NetLogo `=` is used to check equality, not for assignment, so `show random 2 = x` is just going to print `true` or `false` depending on if `random 2` is 0 or not (in case you thought that was assignment).  You'd want something like this:

```
to go 
  ask turtles
  [
    set x random 2
    if x = 1 [set color yellow] 
    if x = 0 [set color pink]
  ]
end
```

Or you could move the `set x random 2` to the `setup` procedure if you just want to set the value once to use later in `go`.

Comment: You can make Jasper's day in return by accepting his answer (using the big checkmark next to it).